# How to restrict the Shipping Country to United States only?

Tags: shipping-address, country-regions

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Amasty extensions
Smartwave Porto theme
```

As a gift shop in the United States, I am only able to ship within the United States yet the drop-down in the Shipping address field contains all world countries. To be clear - I want to allow foreign customers to order from outside the United States if they are ordering a gift for someone in the United States.

I looked at:

- Configuration - Stores - General - Country Options

but these do not seem to be the solution as restricting 'Allow Countries' would not allow people from outside the United States to order a gift for someone living in the United States and 'Top destinations' just seem to put favourite countries up top.

**How could one only show United States in the country drop-down?**

---

Updated on July 27th, 2023:

I am still facing this problem. Surely, there are other merchants who deliver/ship anywhere in the United States but not outside the country yet they want to allow foreign customers to place orders for their relatives/friends in the United States?

Comment: Did you got the solution or are you still looking for the solution?

Comment: @Tarun Bhalodia Hi - Tarun - still looking for an answer.

Comment: Ok @Allysin, I will add the code here once I implement the code in my system and if you fix the problem before that please add comment here.

Comment: @Tarun Bhalodia - Did you ever implement your code and did it work? Would you please share it with us here? Thank you so much!

Comment: I didn't got the chance to look further into it but if you are still looking for the solution then let me work on it and come up with the solution soon.

Comment: @Tarun Bhalodia - yes please and thank you!

Comment: do you have any customisation based on country's IP range location to restrict the countries that are not selected in the configuration that you have mentioned above? Because I tried and it worked, it is showing only United States in the dropdown and allowed me to place order from India.

Comment: I can help you if I can replicate your case in my system, can you please help me with that so I can help you out.

Comment: @Tarun Bhalodia - I'm so sorry - I must be missing something here. I thought the issue was that if you restrict the countries in the Magento Admin panel, it restricts BOTH Ship to and Billing addresses? All of our customers are sending gifts to SOMEONE else so their Shipping and Billing address will always be different! If I restrict in Admin panel to United States only, a person from India will not have India in the list of countries in the Billing Address.